# How to make Autocrat style coffee syrup

Tags: cold-brew

Has anyone tried converting cold brew concentrate into Autocrat style coffee syrup? My daughters enjoy coffee milk.  Can I cold brew the beans in the syrup, or do I need to add sugar to the concentrate and cook it down to a syrup?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to Autocrat coffee syrup, which is basically just corn sugar syrup with a bit of coffee concentrate (and likely some preservatives). So yes you can make it yourself, by making or buying sugar syrup and then add some cold brew concentrate et voilà.

Cold brewing the beans in the sugar syrup I wouldn't try, I don't think it will extract very well, since the syrup is not liquid enough and the water in the syrup already quite saturated with sugars.

If you cook down the cold brew with sugar, it will be super high in caffeine concentrate. I don't know how old your girls are, but high doses of caffeine are not usually recommended for children.